# Name for bipartite graph that allows edges amongst its two sets of nodes.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What can I call a network that has two sets of node (set A and set B), where every node in set A is connected to every node in set B, but there can also be edges between nodes in set A and nodes in set B?

Comment: I guess it's *"$(V, E+E')$ where $(V, E)$ is complete bipartite"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **join of two graphs**. The join $G=G_1+G_2$ of graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with disjoint point sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ and edge sets $E_1$ and $E_2$ is the graph union $G_1$ union $G_2$ together with all the edges joining $V_1$ and $V_2$. For more detail about properties of join, you can see Graph Theory by Harary or Algebraic graph Theorey by Cvetkovic.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard some authors refer to these as bicliques (although other authors reserve this term for an induced complete bipartite graph).